# Fetch current and next row with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have a long query return of which I need to use the current and next row to calculate some results. Can you do this without using fetch all?

I'm not sure how this is duplicate to my question [ref to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430774/mysql-select-one-row-then-one-next-and-one-previous-relative-to-the-selected) [Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense)

My question is PDO not mysql;

Example

```
    |  co1 1   |  col2   |
    |    1     | 444.44  |
    |    2     | 666.66  |
    | ....     | ......  |
    |  99999   | 111.11  |
```

**IN PDO/PHP**

```
        $query   = $pdo>query(sqlQuery);
        while ($rs = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)): 
         #NEED HELP HERE
         if($rs->col2 //row2
              > 
            $rs->col2 //row1
           )
          then{
           do someting...
           }


          endwhile;
         }
```

Hope that gives you an idea of what I want to do

thanks for your help

Comment: Try Using ORDER BY <primary key, or appropriate column> DESC LIMIT 2 ! FETCH can be used, but it will give you single row, If you still can't do it, Please show your Query !

Comment: **`I have a long query`** WHERE is the QUERY

Comment: Yes, dont use `fetch all` just fetch one row at a time in a loop :) `while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {`

Answer (score 1):

```
$query   = $pdo>query(sqlQuery);
$current = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
while ($next = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
    // do your calc here
    $current = $next;
}
```

It's still has not much to do with PDO but with loops in general. PDO doesn't have a method to foresee the next row, if you were asking for this.