# Getting rows from a database around the row selected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I get a row from my database, this row has a field 'sort'. I also wish to return the rows around this row, i.e. if sort of this row is 10, I want rows with sort 9 and 11.

Here's my eloquent:

```
return Products::wherePublished(1)->findOrFail($id, array('title', 'image', 'description','sort'));
```

Is it possible do do this with eloquent or would a regular query have to be made?

Comment: Is there a unique key in that table?

Comment: Yes, 'id' is the unique key

Comment: Select the row in mysql query and add 2 subqueries... 1 to get all rows where id < current_id and LIMIT 1. 2 to to get all rows where id > current_id and LIMIT 1.

Comment: Could you show me an SQL example? Is there no way to do this in eloquent?

Comment: I wrote a query on my table.... worked.............................     Select * from TABLE where ID = 552065 
or
ID = ( Select max(ID) from TABLE where ID < 552065 LIMIT 1) 
or
ID = ( Select min(ID) from TABLE where ID > 552065 LIMIT 1) 
order by ID desc;

Comment: but that selects ids? I need to do it on sort?

Comment: Replace ID = (Select ID from TABLE  where Sort = 10 LIMIT 1);

Comment: Works only when your sort is unique!!. I know query is complex now... but now you can try to optimize

Comment: hmm sort is not unique.

Comment: we need to list all 'id' + 'sort' then apply the logic.. just think

Comment: We can try one option... select * from Table a, (select id, sort from Table) b where a.id=b.id and a.sort=b.sort and OUR BIG QUERY

Comment: Sorry, you are not making much sense.

Comment: To answer your question: no, Eloquent does not provide a way to select a row + nearby rows. Yes, you will have to do a "regular" query.  Various solutions are discussed here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813641/select-a-row-and-rows-around-it